# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, same-origin-policy

I use a JSON response in a Symfony controller. When my result is false, Access-Control-Allow-Origin is OK, but when result is true, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't permit access.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$submited = Request::createFromGlobals();
$id = $submited->request->get('id');

$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$link = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:VisitGoogle')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id, 'status' => 0));

if ($link) {
    $link->setStatus(1);
    $em->persist($link);
    $em->flush();

    $user->setEarn($user->getEarn() + $link->getCredit());
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $response = array("success" => true, 'message' => 'google is ok');
    $response = new JsonResponse($response);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return $response;
} else {
    $response = array("success" => false, 'message' => $this->get('translator')->trans('message.linkiswrong'));
    $response = new JsonResponse($response);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return $response;
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: add controller construct  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    }

Comment: Does not work .

Comment: Do you get a right response when you comment out persist and flush methods? They could fail with an exception so parent controller return another response, without your headers.